# APEX fields on inserted sObject

Tags: apex, soql, insert

I have custom fields on my Account object. Some of them have default value, let say "Days__c" as number with default value 0.

When I insert the object like this:

```
Account account = new Account(Name = 'AccountName');
insert account;
```

Is there a way for me to do

```
account.Days__c
```

to get the default value 0 without querying once again with the required field ? 
After an insert the Id field is available

```
account.Id
```

and I want to do it as well with other fields.

Any ideas ? Thank you.

Comment: No? You will have to query. Or you could simply add the field when creating the account and set it to 0 since you know it defaults to 0. If you need it later just check for null and set it to 0. Lots of ways to do it depending on what your goal is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the default values in one go if you use the `SObjectType.newSObject` method with the signature:

```
public sObject newSObject(ID recordTypeId, Boolean loadDefaults)
```

And since they released the [`getPopulatedFieldsAsMap`](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_apex_sobject_getmap.htm) method, you can now achieve what you want with just one line. As a generic example, run the following in `Execute Anonymous`:

```
static Map<String, Object> getDefaultFieldsAsMap(SObjectType s, Id recordTypeId)
{
    return s.newSObject(recordTypeId, true).getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
}
static Map<String, Object> getDefaultFieldsAsMap(SObjectType s)
{
    return getDefaultFieldsAsMap(s, null);
}

system.debug(getDefaultFieldsAsMap(Account.sObjectType));
```

You can easily drop these methods into a utility class if you want to reuse them elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful.

Any idea why this is not working:
`System.debug(
  Invoice__c.getSObjectType().newSObject('a0A9E0000001PU2UAM', true).getPopulatedFieldsAsMap().get('Name')
);`

With the error:

`Error on line 2, column 1: System.SObjectException: Record Type is Unavailable`

Comment: The key prefix for `RecordType` Id values is `012`. You must use the Id of the `RecordType` you want to load default values for. `a0A` is a custom object prefix. Also, make sure the `RecordType` you select is active. I was able to reproduce this error by deactivating a `RecordType` or using one set up for a different `SObject`. @SimonPlacentino

Answer (score 3):

The [DescribeFieldResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm) class has methods that supply the default values but there are [bugs](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000HXSi). But for a few fields of types not subject to those bugs you could assign the default value using something like:

```
account.Days__c = (Decimal) Account.Days__c.getDescribe.getDefaultValue();
```

Comment: It seems the bug is now fixed by salesforce and you should be able to work with getDescribe and populate default values for all types. https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XL8AAM